# What are the differences between these adb and fastboot packages?

Tags: adb, rooting, usb, bash

In my Bash shell, I have the packages: **adb** vs **android-tools-adb** as well as **fastboot** vs **android-tools-fastboot**.

For reference I am trying to root my device, and later use these tools to learn about how Android works etc.

What are the differences between the packages? Is each one a subset of the other?

Comment: May I recommend you a look into their corresponding tag-wikis: [adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) and [fastboot](/tags/fastboot/info)? That should already answer your question.

Comment: I looked at those, but there is no reference to the respective packages.

Comment: So you know the difference between adb and fastboot? I'd say the respective packages should match that – that the tools-adb package provides adb and the tools-fastboot package provides fastboot, and not vice versa. But reading your question again I just now realize: that's not what you're asking! What distri are you on?

Comment: I am using the Ubuntu app from the Microsoft store.

Comment: Thanks for self-answering! Glad to see the mystery solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorter named packages, adb and fastboot are part of android-platform-system-core, and are minimal versions. Likewise, their longer named counterparts belong to android-tools, and are the full versions. `apt show <package name>` doesn't say much about their differences, except that the adb will break android-tools-adb. The same goes for fastboot.

[This is the homepage](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) for the longer named versions, but it makes no mention of fastboot.

The shorter versions' homepage is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core).